# mpAndroid RealTime data plot in LineChart from sensors in Kotlin, any suggestions to speed up the plot?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am building an Android app in Kotlin and i am really new to this.

My app gets data from a sensor that sends 250 data in one sec (250Hz) and save them in a local file and at the same time send them to a server via HTTP requests.
Also there is the possibility to watch these data in app via a Graph, i choose mpAndroid to plot the data into a linear chart.

I have already everything working 100%, except for the live chart, it works but it has a very slow rendering. It can go up to 3 or 4 minutes of delay since the start of the plotting and i need it as close as possible.

Basically my updateGraph method is triggered by few booleans values. When i click on the button to show the graph the boolean value changes to true and the method that receives data from the sensor starts collecting data into an array.

The updateGraph method is called in the onResume method of the LiveGraph Activity, it gets the array and add the data to the Y axis to plot them and actually it does, but as said with a big delay. I am sure the data are right because on the web server i can see them properly.

This is my main thread:

```
fun renderChartThread() {
    val thread = Thread(Runnable {
            runOnUiThread {
                renderLineChartOnline()
       }
    })
    thread.start()
}
```

This is the renderLineChartOnline method:

```
fun renderLineChartOnline(){

    isRendering = true

    var mChart: LineChart = graph

    yArray.add(Entry(0.toFloat(), 1.20!!.toFloat()))
    set1 = LineDataSet(yArray, "Saved Session")

    set1.setDrawCircles(false);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    set1.setLineWidth(2f)

    val data = LineData(set1)
    mChart.setData(data)

    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    val xAxis = mChart.xAxis
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    xAxis.granularity = 1f 

    xAxis.textSize = 8f

    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xLabel)

}
```

This is the onResume method

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if (MainActivity.isLiveView == true) {

        var mChart: LineChart = graph

       //Getting the data from the device activity
        dataPoints = SocketActivity.liveBRTDataPoint

        updateLiveDataset(dataPoints, mChart)

        }
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 1000)
    }
```

And as last this is my updateGraph method:

```
fun updateLiveDataset(var1: ArrayList<Float>, mChart: LineChart) {

    var i = 0
    mTimer2 = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            i++

            yArray.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), var1[i]!!.toFloat()))

            // limit the number of visible entries
            mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(750f)
            mChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(750f)

            set1 = LineDataSet(yArray, "Live View")
            set1.setDrawCircles(false)
            set1.setDrawValues(false)
            set1.setLineWidth(2f)

            mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

            data = LineData(set1)
            mChart.data = data

            mChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);

            mChart.axisLeft.removeAllLimitLines()
            mChart.axisLeft.resetAxisMaximum()
            mChart.axisLeft.resetAxisMinimum()

            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            mChart.moveViewToX(var1.size.toFloat())

            mChart.invalidate()
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
            mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer2, 4)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution that plot real time data and I would like to post to you the solution, maybe can be helpful to someone else. But this gained another problem, i am missing data in the plot process, off course, because the variable that calls the real time array is not synchronized with the function that receives the data from the device.

This is my updated up code.

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_live_graph.*
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream


class LiveGraph : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{
        var isRendering:Boolean = false
        var isEcg:Boolean = false
        var isBrt:Boolean = false
    }

    lateinit var chart: LineChart

    var dataPoints = ArrayList<Float>()
    var pre_filter = ArrayList<Float>()
    var yArray = ArrayList<Entry>()
    lateinit var set1: LineDataSet
    var xLabel = ArrayList<String>()
    var data = LineData()

    private val mHandler: Handler = Handler()
    private var mTimer2: Runnable? = null

    lateinit var file: String

    var thread: Thread? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_graph)


        // lock the current device orientation
        val currentOrientation = this.resources.configuration.orientation
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        } else {
            this.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }

        // Keep screen awake
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        chart = graph

        run(chart)

    }

    fun renderChartOnline(data: ArrayList<Float>, chart: LineChart) {

        var i = 0
        if (data.size>0){
            for (d in data) {
                i +=1
                yArray.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), d.toFloat()))
                var sec = i/250.toFloat()
                val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

                if (sec > 60){
                    var min = sec/60.toFloat()
                    xLabel.add(min.toString()+"min")
                } else{
                    xLabel.add(sec.toString()+"sec")
                }
            }
        }else{
            yArray.add(Entry(0.toFloat(), 1.20!!.toFloat()))
        }

        set1 = LineDataSet(yArray, "Saved Session")

        set1.setDrawCircles(false);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
        set1.setLineWidth(2f)

        val data = LineData(set1)
        chart.setData(data)

        chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        val xAxis = chart.xAxis
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.granularity = 1f // only intervals of 1 day

        xAxis.textSize = 8f

        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xLabel)

        chart.invalidate()
    }

   
    fun run(chart: LineChart){
       
            runOnlineGraph()
            val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        }

    fun runOnlineGraph(){
        isRendering = true
        feedMultiple()
    }

    private fun feedMultiple() {
        if (thread != null) thread!!.interrupt()

        val runnable = Runnable { addEntry() }

        thread = Thread(Runnable {
            while (true) {
                runOnUiThread(runnable)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        })
        thread!!.start()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        dataPoints = SocketActivity.liveECGDataPoint
        renderChartOnline(dataPoints, chart)
    }

    private fun addEntry() {

      /***
         * Whit this i get the data saved in the Socket process, 
         * but this gives me the problem of missing datas received, 
         * if i use an array the delay increase too much then, 
         * so i m still looking for a solution to this point
         */

  
        dataPoints = SocketActivity.liveDataForGraph
        val data = chart.data
        if (data != null) {
            var set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0)
            // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well
            if (set1 == null) {
                data.addDataSet(set)
            }
            for (i in dataPoints){
                data.addEntry(
                    Entry(
                        set.entryCount.toFloat(),
                        i
                    ), 0
                )

            data.notifyDataChanged()

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            chart.notifyDataSetChanged()

            // move to the latest entry
            chart.moveViewToX(data.entryCount.toFloat())

            // limit the number of visible entries
            chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(750f)
            chart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(750f)

            chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
            // move to the latest entry
            chart.moveViewToX(data.entryCount.toFloat())

            chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);

            chart.axisLeft.removeAllLimitLines()
            chart.axisLeft.resetAxisMaximum()
            chart.axisLeft.resetAxisMinimum()

            chart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // let the chart know it's data changed

            chart.invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer2);

        isRendering = false
    }
}
```